# Error installing pip on linux

Tags: python, linux

I am running Raspbian Linux on a Raspberry Pi, and I have both `python`, `python3`, and `pip` installed. When I run `sudo pip install pillow`, I get a very large output of code. The first error is `Failed building wheel for pillow`, after which is says that it failed to build pillow and will install pillow.

At the very end of the code, I have this error in red:

```
Command "/usr/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-Yhx8TM/pillow/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.rea                                                                          
d().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-yjhZ83-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-m                                                                          
anaged --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-Yhx8TM/pillow/
```

I have been following the installation instructions from https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html and have not found a solution there.

I haven't found any similar errors online yet.

UPDATE: I have tried installing cython, updating gcc and g++. I have also tried running `python -m pip install pillow`. I have tried installing django through pip, and I get this as an error:

```
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 342, in run
    prefix=options.prefix_path,
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 784, in install
    **kwargs
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 851, in install
    self.move_wheel_files(self.source_dir, root=root, prefix=prefix)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 1064, in move_wheel_files
    isolated=self.isolated,
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 345, in move_wheel_files
    clobber(source, lib_dir, True)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 316, in clobber
    ensure_dir(destdir)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/utils/__init__.py", line 83, in ensure_dir
    os.makedirs(path)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 157, in makedirs
    mkdir(name, mode)
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pytz'
```

UPDATE: I have installed pip3 for python3 and I run into the same exact problem as earlier.

Comment: `Failed to build` errors tend to appear because of the `gcc` and `g++` compilers in my experience. Upgrading these and installing `cython` might help.

Comment: Can you pip install other packages? I also think its not pip/python to blame, worth poking around

Comment: Bear in mind you should use the `pip3` command, not `pip`, to install things for Python 3.

Comment: If you read through the error log in the external paste, you would see this line: `The headers or library files could not be found for jpeg,`. This means you don't have libjpeg installed. Install that and zlib before doing pip install. Your problem is not with gcc. As for your last block of error, assuming sudo is installed, use `sudo python -m pip ....`

Comment: @SuperSaiyan I installed `libjpeg-dev`, `zlib1g-dev`, and `libpng-dev`. Afterwards I ran `sudo python -m pip install pillow` and everything worked perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: Please never post ephemeral content like paste.ofcode.org on Stack Overflow.